# Unable to include external jars

Tags: java

I am not able to include include external jars from command line on ubuntu linux while compiling my java program.My external jars are in /home/ubuntu/lib directory
Im using this:

javac -cp /home/ubuntu/lib c.java

but it fails to compile.Can anyone suggest what im doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Error message is on the lines which need external jar like  cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpClient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
javac -cp "/home/ubuntu/lib/*" c.java
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I was had not put the astriek also I had tried with *.jar wierd it only accepts *.But thanks much!!!

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify the jars directly as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try placing the jar files in the ext folder of your `jdk/jre/lib/ext` folder.